# Angular - Can't resolve all parameters for service (?)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I'm running into an issue with my simple Angular application that I am having trouble debugging. Whenever I try to inject a service into the constructor I get the an error saying Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService (?)

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    template: require('./app.component.html')
})
export default class AppComponent {

constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}
```

}

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

login() {
    // Do http requests here
}
```

}

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

// Components
import AppComponent from './app.component';

//Services
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [LoginService, HttpClient],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export default class AppModule {}
```

Seems to be a problem around the injection of the HttpClient but I cant figure out what exactly.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Migh be the path of impott is wrong or may be misspelled lIke in actual capital L is there but you spelled it small l

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need `HttpClient` in your `app.module.ts`, it should only be imported in the service

Comment: @Und3rTow, you're right thanks, removing, I was getting desperate!

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be a missing import!

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Comment: glad i stumbled across this
when i upgraded from angular 6 to 7, i kept getting can not resolve all parameters for HttpXSRFInterceptor... even though i wasn't even using that interceptor... adding this to polyfills.ts fixed issue

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you've upgraded to Angular 9+ but have disabled Ivy and you're using a library that was compiled with ngc with Ivy turned on. The solution is to upgrade to Ivy or to ask the library owner to produce a non-Ivy build as well.